# When I type sudo -i nautilus, nautilus opens and shows an error

Tags: permissions, nautilus, sudo

After launching nautilus with `sudo -i nautilus` it opens and shows this message:

> Oops! unable to create the required folder.
>   Please create the folder or set permission to create the folder: `/root/.config/nautilus`

I have tried creating the folder in terminal but it says the folder already exists.

Comment: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/904151/edit) your post to include the output of `ls -l /root/.config/nautilus`

Comment: Please don't use sudo with Nautilus. It is very easy to break something. And as stated by hamiheim: check and restore the permissions of that file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me preface my answer by saying **it's best not to use sudo with nautilus!** That being said, if you still want to, be really careful and ...

You may be able to drop the `-i` switch so that your command is `sudo -H nautilus`. This would prevent you from seeing the error you're seeing.

---

**If you want to keep the `-i` switch:**

Make sure that /root/.config/nautilus is a directory and not a file, and try running these two commands just to make sure permissions are correct.

```
sudo chown root:root /root/.config/nautilus
sudo chmod 755 /root/.config/nautilus
```

*Note: those last two commands will only work in `/root/.config/nautilus` already exists*

Now, try your command again.

---

**If it still doesn't work:**

Perhaps something has happened to the permissions on  the parent directory

```
sudo chown root:root /root/.config
sudo chmod 700 /root/.config
```

Comment: I recommend against using sudo with nautilus for a couple reasons. 1) Nautilus run with sudo and nautilus not run with sudo look almost identical. It's easy to confuse the windows if you have multiple instances open. 2) If you run nautilus with sudo, you can create headache for yourself, especially if you forget it was opened with sudo. What if someone else uses the sudo window to make changes? It could be disastrous. What if you create stuff in your home directory. You'll have to go back and change permissions on everything you create if you want to access it from your normal user account.

Comment: @DKBose, Thanks. gksudo doesn't seem to be installed in 16.04 by default, but the -H switch works!

Comment: `sudo nautilus` is the only way I am able to open Nautilus as root. Not sure why I keep seeing all this `sudo -i` stuff because it doesn't make a difference... You'll still have root access to your entire PC and can easily make mistakes regardless. `sudo -i nautilus` `kdesudo nautilus` (I use Plasma 5.8.5) doesn't work, `gksudo nautilus`, `pkexec nautilus` etc these commands all result in a segmentation fault for me.